# Profile Specific Logic in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, customlabel

I have to disable buttons for three profiles. like A, B and C. I want to achieve something like.. for all values in custom labels. Can I put all profiles name ie. A, B, & C in custom label, it should be disabled. How can I achieve this?

```
<apex:commandButton disabled="{!IF(CONTAINS(!$Label. ,''),true,false)}" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `Hierarchy Custom Setting`. Add a checkbox called `Is_Disabled__c`. Set the org wide default to false. Create a record for each profile you wish to disable and set the checkbox to true. Then in your page you can check:

```
$Setup.MySetting__c.Is_Disabled__c
```

Naming will naturally vary depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks Adrian..You mean like  apex:commandButton disabled="$Setup.MySetting__c.Is_Disabled__c"

Comment: Exactly. @David

Comment: Thanks All. Would it work for Output panel too. Like if i want to hide output panel on the basis of same customsetting. How can we achieve that.

Comment: Yeah you probably want a separate checkbox but the process is the same. Also note that the setting *can* be specified at the user level, and the most specific setting wins. Should be moot, just wanted to point it out.

Comment: apex:variable value="test" var="Test1" rendered="{!$Setup.MySetting__c.Is_Disabled__c}">..

Comment: For output panel its not working i have taken output panel in variable..not working please suggest

Comment: Let's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40785/mycka-profile-vf), comments are not a good forum for extended discussion.